# How to pass in multiple parameter values into an SQLQuery in loadrunner

Tags: sql, parameters, loadrunner

Good day,

I am aware this might be a simple question, but I am new at this, I am attempting to pass in multiple parameter values to an SQL query in LoadRunner 20. This is with SQL.

the problem is simple

I have to insert statement

```
INSERT into table ([name],[surname],[date]) VALUES ({name_parameters},{surname_parameter}, GetDATE())
```

How do I pass in a value into both NAME and SURNAME without upsetting LR, I thus far been using lr_eval_string but that only accepts a single parameter and goes haywire when i introduce the second one in the same query.

SOLUTION:

My solution would be to save a parameter from either, then pass in that parameter as a STRING in the query in the statement?

but i do not know how to, can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

```
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("INSERT into table ([name],[surname],[date]) VALUES ({name_parameters},{surname_parameter}, GetDATE())"), "SQL");
```

this actually should work, no?

or try:

```
lr_param_sprintf("SQL", "INSERT into table ([name],[surname],[date]) VALUES (%s,%s, GetDATE())", lr_eval_string("{name_parameters}"), lr_eval_string("{surname_parameter}"));
```